# Booting from USB in win 10- What are the factors involved?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, windows-10, usb

I got an Asus laptop recently, and it cannot boot properly from USB at all. Ubuntu, Clonezilla and Minitool Partition Wizard all crashed while booting. Curiously, they all crashed DURING boot, as in the boot started but then somehow failed halfway through.

What are the factors that affect USB booting? I am aware of the CSM setting in the BIOS, Secure Boot and Fast Boot. Is there anything else which plays a part?boo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem's with the laptop. Still not fixed it though. For those who see this in the future, check these steps:

1)Test with another pendrive.

2)Test on another laptop.

3)Test multiple bootable apps.

4)Try multiple means of creating bootable media.

5)Test all USB ports.

All these gave me the same crash. If all these steps fail, the issue's with the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Quality and speed of the USB drive can be a massive factor, I would defiantly try a different USB drive, preferably of good quality. Also USB3 and USB2 devices can have differences depending on your motherboard.

Another factor is the quality of your images, do you check the check-sums of your bootable images before writing them?

Finally, there are different methods of making a USB bootable. I would suggest to try others such as [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) or [Universal Linux Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)

Comment: I'll try with a different USB. How would the fact that the same bootable USB works on my other laptop change your response?

Also, how to do the check sum thing? I am using Rufus at the moment.

Comment: That would say so me that your USB drive is probably fine and would negate that as part of my answer. Check-sums are a good way to check you have downloaded what you have intended and it has not been tampered with in any way, most downloads these days offer an MD5 Checksum value alongside their downloads. there are many tools available to check the check-sum of a downloaded file. When compared with the published MD5 on the website if they are the same you can be sure that the file has not corrupted nor been tampered with in any way